# How do i get the url from firebase databse to in my flutter project

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i'm trying to get the URL so i can use flutter_downloader package to download images from Firebase
the URL is in the image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkOVn.png)

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you checked the docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup)?

Comment: Would you mind to re phase the issue?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please,  share some code so we can better help you. Please, take a time to read about [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// First create a firestore instance
Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance; 

// Access the desired collection and document
var result = await _firestore.collection('wallpapers').document(id).get();

// Your url
result['url']
```